# The set of all bounded multilinear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, multilinear-algebra

I'm not sure how to show that the set of all bounded multilinear maps is a vector space. Could someone help me?

Comment: Is the sum of two bounded multilinear maps a bounded multilinear map? If you multiply by a scalar, does it change whether something is bounded or multilinear? Is there a zero object? There's a list of requirements for something to be a vector space - have you tried checking each one?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** First, you want to show that the $0$ map is bounded and multilinear.

Then, you need to demonstrate that if $f,g$ are bounded multilinear maps, and $\alpha$ is an element of your original field, then $\alpha f + g$ is also a bounded multilinear map.